CICS WEB RECEIVE data missing
I execute this code:
E0198            EXEC CICS WEB RECEIVE SESSTOKEN(WS-SESSION-TOKEN)
E0198                 STATUSCODE(WS-HTTP-STATUS-CD)
E0198                 STATUSTEXT(WS-HTTP-STATUS-TEXT)
E0198                 STATUSLEN(WS-HTTP-STATUS-TEXT-LEN)
E0198                 INTO (EPS-Q-DATA)
E0198                 LENGTH(WS-RECEIVE-LENGTH)
E0198                 MAXLENGTH(WS-RECEIVE-MAX-LENGTH)
E0198                 NOTRUCATE
E0198                 CLICONVERT
E0198                 RESP(WS-RESP)
E0198                 RESP2(WS-RESP2)
E0198            END-EXEC
E0198            IF (WS-RESP-NORMAL OR WS-RESP-EOC OR WS-RESP-SIGNAL
E0198               OR  (WS-RESP-INVREQ AND WS-RESP2 = 41)
E0198               OR  (WS-RESP-LENGERR AND WS-RESP2 = 36))
E0198               AND (WS-HTTP-STATUS-CD
E0198                                   EQUAL 0 OR 200)
***** *>>>>>>>>>>> DEBUG -- SEE WHAT WE GOT
E0198               EXEC CICS WRITEQ TS QUEUE ('BIASBIAS')
E0198                                   FROM (EPS-Q-DATA)
E0198                                   LENGTH (WS-RECEIVE-LENGTH)
E0198                                   ITEM (WS-ITEM)
E0198                                   NOHANDLE
E0198               END-EXEC

EDF shows:


More information:
05  EPS-Q-DATA    PIC X(1024) VALUE SPACES.
10  WS-RECEIVE-LENGTH           PIC  9(08) COMP VALUE 0.
How is it that I can see the data in EDF, but when I try to "print" the data, it is not there.  Where did it go???  For the record, the receive has executed multiple times.  I see the data change each time.

I'd remove the IF and see if the data is written to the queue.  If that works, then I would add one condition at a time back to the IF and retest.  I suspect one of your IF conditions is making the IF false.

the IF cannot be an issue.  The EXEC CICS WRITEQ is being executed.

It’s difficult without seeing the full program. However the WEB RECEIVE for LENGTH expects a fullword where the WRITEQ TS expects a half word. So I suspect the data is still all there and it’s this length difference that is causing the issue.

Thank you Adam... tell the wife... you were right :)

It’s difficult without seeing the full program. However the WEB RECEIVE for LENGTH expects a fullword where the WRITEQ TS expects a half word. So I suspect the data is still all there and it’s this length difference that is causing the issue.
